# jwplayer not display in my case

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jwplayer

please help me fix this script:

```
<?php $aaa = "<script>document.writeln(enc)</script>"; 
?>

var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
        width: '100%',
        height: '360',
        title: 'aaaaa',
        description: 'dcascd',
        file: window.atob('<?php echo $aaa; ?>'),

});
```

my ext javascript

```
var str= "http://example.com/video.mp4";
    enc = window.btoa(str);
enc = String(enc);
```

player not display. please help me fix this code.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$aaa` equals a script tag, so you'd end up with:

```
    file: window.atob('<script>document.writeln(enc)</script>'),
```

You must remember, PHP compiles first, then JS runs after it.

---

The order would be:

#### 1.

`$aaa` would equal `<script>document.writeln(enc)</script>`

#### 2.

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    width: '100%',
    height: '360',
    title: 'aaaaa',
    description: 'dcascd',
    file: window.atob('<script>document.writeln(enc)</script>"; ?>'),
});
```

Comment: how to take value javascript in php

Comment: Also you have a trailing comma. There should be no comma for this line - file: window.atob('<script>document.writeln(enc)</script>"; ?>'),